# Custom Date Fields in CMS Block in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

I am creating a module and i want a custom date fields in cms block in magento 2. Via UI component i crated a two date field.

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
 <fieldset name="general">       
       <field name="custom_block_from">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">From</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">block</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">custom_block_from</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="validate-date" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                        </item>                 
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="custom_block_to">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">21</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">To</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">block</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">custom_block_to</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="validate-date" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Via Upgrade Script i also add two colummn in CMS block table in magento which are

```
public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        if ($installer->tableExists('cms_block')) {
            $table = $installer->getTable('cms_block');
            $connection = $installer->getConnection();
            if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.2') < 0) {
                $connection->addColumn(
                    $table,
                    'custom_block_from',
                    [
                        'type' => Table::TYPE_DATE,
                        'nullable' => true,
                        'comment' => 'date'
                    ]
                );
                $connection->addColumn(
                    $table,
                    'custom_block_to',
                    [
                        'type' => Table::TYPE_DATE,
                        'nullable' => true,
                        'comment' => 'date'
                    ]
                );              
            }
            $installer->endSetup();
        }
    }
```

Now two fields are created in CMS Block but when i saved cms block that date field value is not saving in database. But when i changed Date fields via sql than that fields get value from database and is showing in cms block edit and after saved again that date fields turns 0000-00-00.

Please if someone help me on this. Very Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date fields have to be formatted before saved to the db. In your case

```
foreach (['custom_block_from', 'custom_block_to'] as $field) {
    $value = !$object->getData($field) ? null : $this->dateTime->formatDate($object->getData($field));
    $object->setData($field, $value);
}
```

This code has to be called before the cms block is saved.

So even your override the Class

/vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/ResourceModel/Block.php

using a preference

```
<preference for="Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block" type="Your_Vendor\Your_Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Block" />
```

and adding the function below

```
    /**
 * Perform operations before object save
 *
 * @param AbstractModel $object
 * @return $this
 * @throws LocalizedException
 */
protected function _beforeSave(AbstractModel $object)
{
    foreach (['custom_block_from', 'custom_block_to'] as $field) {
        $value = !$object->getData($field) ? null : $this->dateTime->formatDate($object->getData($field));
        $object->setData($field, $value);
    }

    if (!$this->getIsUniqueBlockToStores($object)) {
        throw new LocalizedException(
            __('A block identifier with the same properties already exists in the selected store.')
        );
    }
    return $this;
}
```

or using the event cms_block_save_before.

Comment: No prob. Please accept my answer if you think was useful.

Comment: Niko one more thing if you can help me out, on basis of this Date i am try to show hide block.
For this i just make a condition in static block but this will only work if i flush cache. So user are not going to flush every time, is that any other method that i can use.

Comment: if you include your cms block via layout , maybe you try to use the attribute cacheable="false" for this block in layout. Check also this https://firebearstudio.com/blog/magento-2-custom-block-caching.html

Comment: Thanks For reply ,
Actually i just showing that block via admin pages. But when applying condition it don't Work

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i came across your answer after this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093924/custom-date-fields-in-cms-block-in-magento-2 and then i was like .... hang on ....